# Django, abstract model class + derived model & form "exclude" field issue

Tags: django, model, abstract

```
class SomeBaseClass(models.Model):
    CHOICES_1 = (
     (1, '1'),
     (2, '2'),
     (3, '3'),
     (4, '4'),
     )
    ONETIME = 'OT'
    WEEKLY = 'WK'
    BIWEEKLY = 'BW'
    MONTHLY = 'MN'
    BIMONTHLY = 'BM'
    YEARLY = 'YR'
    CHOICES_2 = (
        (ONETIME, 'One Time'),
        (WEEKLY, 'Weekly'),
        (BIWEEKLY, 'Bi-Weekly'),
        (MONTHLY, 'Monthly'),
        (BIMONTHLY, 'Bi-Monthly'),
        (YEARLY, 'Yearly'),
    )
    CHOICES_3 = (
         (0,'0'),
         (1,'1'),
         (2,'2'),
         (3,'3'),
         (4,'4'),
         (5,'5'),
         (10,'10'),
    )
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    field3 = models.DateField()
    field4 = models.TimeField()
    field5 = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES_1)
    field6 = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=CHOICES_2)
    field7 = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=CHOICES_3)
    field8 = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    field9 = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeDerivedClass(SomeBaseClass):
    field10 = models.DateTimeField()
    field11 = models.ForeignKey(Business, blank=True)


class SomeDerivedClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeDerivedClass
        exclude = ['field2']
        exclude = ['field10']
        exclude = ['field11']
```

When the "SomeDerivedClassForm" is rendered, the field10 shows up on the website even though I've set it to be excluded.  Prior to this I had field11 in the base class, and at that time field10 was not shown in the rendered form but field11 was showing up even though it's excluded.  I realize I must have some bug in my code but I'm not seeing what it is.
Do you need to do anything special to use forms with derived classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is that simple.

Instead of this in your code, here you are overwriting the `exclude` list every time you want to add a field to it.

```
 exclude = ['field2']
 exclude = ['field10']
 exclude = ['field11']
```

write:

```
 exclude = ['field2', 'field10', 'field11']
```

Comment: Yes, that was correct solution to my problem.  I don't know why it wasn't intuitive to me in the first place?  You would figure after 15 years of programming I would have learned a thing or two.  Thanks again for the fix.